# How to remove the safe area margin in xamarin ios

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, safearealayoutguide

I want to remove safe area margin for all my view controller views. I have tried the below code but it is not working. I dont know how to remove the safe area margin.

```
public override UIEdgeInsets AdditionalSafeAreaInsets { get => base.AdditionalSafeAreaInsets; set => base.AdditionalSafeAreaInsets = value; }

AdditionalSafeAreaInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(0,0,0,0);
```

and unchecked the Safe Area Relative margin in Storyboard. But the safe area is not removed. Please give your suggestion to remove the safe area margin.

[image: image screenshot]

[image: Layout Image]

Comment: Basically you want to globally remove safe area?

Comment: @FreakyAli, Yes I want to remove the safe area globally.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout

Comment: @sermet, I am using xamarin.ios native. not xamarin.forms

Comment: Hi , I have tried again in Xamarin iOS , if view created in a stroyboard , u can share the screenshot of view's proeperty about Layout here . https://i.stack.imgur.com/hN1RE.png

Comment: Hi @JuniorJiang-MSFT, Please refer my updated screenshot

Comment: @DotNetUser Thanks , if setting `Y` to be `0` , does it top to the top area ?

Comment: @DotNetUser Regarding first screenshot It seems that can't see the relationship with safearea. You can update two screenshots or renderings in the question. One is the current effect and the other is the desired effect.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following steps:

1. Open storyboard and check Safe area autolayout guides true.
2. After doing this give superview's top bottom left right constraints to Safe Area instead of layout margin.
3. So superview will fit inside the safe area in all iOS devices.

[image]

Comment: You mean checked? we should not uncheck.

Comment: Sorry Checked, but still margin visible

Comment: Could you post the screenshot?

Comment: Please refer my screenshot